Postman not working with Entity Framework API but browser does
I made a project using Entity Framework and .net7. It's uploaded in a remote server and running on IIS.
Using browser or any programming language like Laravel with the APIs works fine but not on Postman. I get this error:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
Request Headers
Authorization: Bearer <token>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.41.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: <token>
Host: host.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Sometimes, it just works again, but I just pushed a simple change now it's now working on Postman.
What is this issue and how can I fix this?

Connection Refused is a low level routing issue. It means that your request from POSTMAN is attempting to reach an endpoint that is not responding to HTTP requests. Unlikely to be anything relating to EF itself. Why it works with browsers etc.? Could be you're using a different endpoint, response caching, or something like a load balancer issue where routing in some situations are going to a properly configured server while others are going to a faulty one.

This error may be due to a problem with the way Postman is making the request, or there may be some specific conditions that only affect the connection in Postman. You can try using a network capture tool(such as Fiddler or Wireshark) to analyze what happens when Postman tries to connect, which may further help determine why the connection is being refused.
